# On every 'save' in Eclipse: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.FeatureNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, servlets, servlet-3.0, m2e

In my Eclipse Oxygen, I get this error on every save.

From reading around, it seems to come from some version incompatibility in the Servlet standard used but I am not sure what is incompatible with what.

How do I fix this?

> An internal error occurred during: "Loading descriptor for project1.". org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.FeatureNotFoundException:
>    Feature 'init-param' not found. (platform:/resource/project1/war/WEB-INF/web.xml, 72, 14)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a screenshot of a similar problem

[image]

The problem is that the [DTD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307571/what-is-dtd-exactly) specified in `web.xml`, generally specified in the `web-app` element, does not match the actual structure of the `web.xml`.
The error message points to the line (circled in the screenshot) in the `web.xml` document which is problematic.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee;http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

So either

1. remove the DTD ([it is not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187949/is-it-mandatory-to-specify-dtd-in-xml), but it is helpful to show your incompatibilities)
2. update the `web.xml` to fit the DTD
3. update the DTD to fit the `web.xml`